# Camera2: Should createCaptureRequest() be called on a background thread

Tags: android, android-camera2

From documentation:

> Creating a session is an expensive operation and can take several hundred milliseconds, since it requires configuring the camera device's internal pipelines and allocating memory buffers for sending images to the desired targets. Therefore the setup is done asynchronously, and CameraDevice#createCaptureSession and CameraDevice#createReprocessableCaptureSession will send the ready-to-use CameraCaptureSession to the provided listener's CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback#onConfigured callback.

However, I am getting an ANR caused by createCaptureSession():

```
AppNotResponding : Application not responsive since: Fri Jan 17 17:19:26 GMT+01:00 2020
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:510)
        at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.endConfigure(ICameraDeviceUser.java:719)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.endConfigure(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:114)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.configureStreamsChecked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:476)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:664)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:512)
```

I don't see in code examples that createCaptureSession() call is being made on a background thread. Usually there is a handler being passed so only callbacks would be executed on background thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the official [Camera2 sample](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) by Google, the preview session is created in separate HandlerThread. The camera session is created like 
                   `mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                        mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);`